# iOS is creating a JSON String without {} -- only has [ ]?

Tags: ios, json

Why is the assignment to jsonString not including braces{}?

Here's what I'm getting:

> ["anemail@chdr.com"]

**CODE**

```
if (_allEmails)
        {
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:_allEmails options:0 error:&error];
            if (!error)
            {

                NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                [dictionary setObject:jsonString forKey:@"AllEmails"];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show the code where you're declaring and initializing `_allEmails`.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  Then you will understand why the above is correct (or at least valid JSON).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_allEmails` variable must be an array (you tell me) and for braces you need to store your data in a dictionary.

Perhaps what you're looking for is:

```
if ([_allEmails count] > 0)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"AllEmails" : _allEmails };
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];
    // Note: Check returned object and not NSError object
    if (jsonData) {
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // Do thing with string
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to serialize JSON: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was it - this was due to my being unfamiliar with JSON. What I needed was an array of dictionaries (one dict for each email).

Answer (score 1):

Because a JSON array is not enclosed braces, and what you have above is a JSON array.  A JSON "object" is enclosed in braces.